# Don't understand how apply gets its parameters in r

Tags: r, apply

I am struggling to make my `apply()` work: I have two `dataframe`s:

```
from <- c(1,2,3)
to <- c(2,3,4)
df1 <- data.frame(from, to)

long <-c(9,9.2,9.4,9.6)
lat <- c(45,45.2,45.4,45.6)
id <- c(1,2,3,4)
df2 <- data.frame(long, lat, id)
```

Now I want something like this:

```
myFunction <- function(arg){
  >>> How do I access arg$from and arg$to? <<<<
}
apply(df1,1,myFunction)
```

In `myFunction` I need to make some calculations and return a value for each `from-to` pair. I don't understand how to access parts of the `arg`, since `arg[0]` gives me `numeric(0)` and `arg$from` just crashes.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to do. But if you're unaware that vectors in R are 1 indexed, not 0 indexed, you should probably read some basic tutorials before proceeded further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `apply(...)` requires a matrix or array as the first argument. If you pass a dataframe, it will coerce that to a matrix. Matrices are 1 indexed, so the upper left element is [1,1], not [0,0]. Also, matrix columns cannot be referenced using the `$` notation.

So,

```
f <- function(x) {
  from <- x[1]
  to   <- x[2]
  # do stuff with from and to...
}

apply(df,1,f)
```

would work.

One other thing to watch out for is that if your dataframe has (other) columns that have character strings, the conversion will make *everything* character (including the numbers!). This is because, by definition, all elements of a matrix must have the same data type. Your example does not have that problem, though.

Answer (score 1):

Try `mapply()`. It's a multivariate version of `sapply()`. For example:

```
> myFunction <- function(arg1, arg2){
+     return(sum(arg1, arg2))
+ }
> 
> mapply(myFunction, df1$from, df1$to)
[1] 3 5 7
```

You can also use it to make a new variable in your data frame.

```
> df1$newvar <- mapply(myFunction, df1$from, df1$to)
> df1
  from to newvar
1    1  2      3
2    2  3      5
3    3  4      7
```